# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getattr'

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, attributeerror

I am trying to get the worker_manager to work, but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiQueue2.py", line 61, in <module>
    manager.generate(control, threadName, i)
  File "multiQueue2.py", line 38, in generate
    target = i.getattr(name)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'getattr'
```

Here is the code I am working with, worker_manager, is the only part that will be going live. It is supposed to take thread names from the dictionary and then access the associated classes. Any advice anyone? Thanks!

```
import multiprocessing 
import time 

class test_imports:#Test classes remove 
      def import_1(self, control_queue, thread_number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_number
          run = True
          count = 1
          while run:
                alive = control_queue.get()
                if alive == 't1kill':
                   print ("Killing thread type 1 number %d") % thread_number
                   run = False
                   break
                print ("Thread type 1 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count)
                count = count + 1

      def import_2(self, control_queue, thread_number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_number
          run = True
          count = 1
          while run:
                alive = control_queue.get()
                if alive == 't2kill':
                   print ("Killing thread type 2 number %d") % thread_number
                   run = False
                   break
                print ("Thread type 2 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count)           
                count = count + 1

class worker_manager:
    # ...
    names = {'one': 'import_1', 'two': 'import_2'}
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
    def generate(self, control_queue, threadName, runNum):
        name = self.names[threadName]
        target = i.getattr(name) #THis is throwing the error
        print ("Starting %s number %d") % (name, runNum)
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=target, args=(control_queue, runNum))
        self.children[threadName] = p
        p.start()
    def terminate(self, threadName):
        self.children[threadName].join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Establish communication queues
    control = multiprocessing.Queue()
    manager = worker_manager()    
    runNum = int(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) 
    threadNum = int(raw_input("Enter number of threads: "))
    threadName = raw_input("Enter number: ")
    thread_Count = 0

    print ("Starting threads") 

    for i in range(threadNum):
        if threadName == 'three':
            manager.generate(control, 'one', i)
            manager.generate(control, 'two', i)
        manager.generate(control, threadName, i)
        thread_Count = thread_Count + 1              
        if threadName == 'three':
            thread_Count = thread_Count + 1 

    time.sleep(runNum)#let threads do their thing

    print ("Terminating threads")     

    for i in range(thread_Count):
        control.put("t1kill")
        control.put("t2kill")
    if threadName == 'three':
        manager.terminate('one')
        manager.terminate('two')
    else:
        manager.terminate(threadName)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def generate(self, control_queue, threadName, runNum):
    name = self.names[threadName]
    target = i.getattr(name) #THis is throwing the error
```

`i` here is not defined in the local scope. That means it's defined globally. Which means that the variable you are referring to is the one defined here:

```
for i in range(threadNum):
```

If that is intentional, it's bad practice. Try to avoid using global variables.
Also, that's an integer. You are trying to do:

```
  i.getattr(name)
```

on the integer. What is that supposed to do? There is a function called `getattr` to get dynamically defined attributes, but integers don't have any dynamic attributes anyway, so it's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to use the dictionary to reference function calls. What should i be using in place of target = i.getattr(name)

Comment: @KyleSponable You should replace `i` with the variable name that actually contains the dictionary you need an attribute from.

Comment: @KyleSponable: `target = thedictionaryinquestion[name]` I'm not sure what dictionary you are trying to use. Is it perhaaps `names`? That's the only dictionary I see. Your code seems very complex for doing very little.